# Approximation argument for Cauchy's theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

In a simply connected region $U$, do functions of the form $\frac{1}{z-a}$, for $a\notin U$, generate all analytic functions in $U$ in some way? For example as limits of linear combinations of these functions? Is there an alternate proof of Cauchy's theorem using this?

Answer (score 2):

Since "generate" is a broad term, I will answer the part regarding limits of linear combination:

A series of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-a_n} $$ with $\{ a_n \} \notin U$, could never generate an entire function, since the points $\{a_n \}$ are all poles. Thus for example $e^z:U \to \mathbb C$ cannot be represented in this manner.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the argument.  Sure, the functions $\frac{1}{z-a_n}$ each fail to be analytic, but this only occurs outside of $U$ - on $U$, each *is* analytic.  For a dumb example, if $U = D(0,1)$, then the functions $f(z) = e^z + \frac{1}{z-2}$ and $g(z) = -\frac{1}{z-2}$ both fail to be analytic on all of $\mathbb{C}$, but nonetheless $e^x = f(z) + g(z)$ on $U$.  (But no, I don't see how to write $e^z$ as a linear combination of functions of the form $\frac{1}{z-a_n}$.)

Comment: @JasonDeVito what about analytic continuation? Also, in your example you didn't create $\exp$ from those functions.

Comment: Cauchy's theorem says that if integral over any closed curve of 1/z-a is 0 for every a not in U, then integral over any closed curve of every analytic function is 0. So I think there should be a relation between these functions.

Comment: @user1337:  I'm probably misreading your argument, but here is how I read it:  "Each function of the form $\frac{1}{z-a_n}$ has poles.  Since the $a_n$ are different, the poles can't cancel in any way, so $\sum \frac{1}{z-a_n}$ has poles.  Thus, $e^z$, having no poles, can't be given as a linear combination of them."  The objection I'm making is that for a particular $U$, perhaps none of the $\frac{1}{z-a_n}$ have poles on $U$, and so it's not clear to me why $e^z|_U$ cannot be equal to $\left(\sum \frac{1}{z-a_n}\right)|_U$.

Comment: (Also, my example does create $e^z$ from $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ *on $U$*, or I'm even more confused than I think I am.)

Comment: The first part of your comment about analytic continuation just registered in my head - I think I get it now.  Sorry to be so dense!

Comment: @JasonDeVito It's okay, I was having doubts myself too.